# How to read a single CLI keypress from Python 3 on Unix without requiring ENTER or root privileges?

Tags: python, python-3.x, unix, keyboard, keyboard-events

The problem described in the title is, apparently, incredibly hard.  Every solution I have found for it (and there are ***dozens*** of them in SO alone) is inadequate for at least one of the following reasons:

- Python 2-specific;
- unnecessarily portable/cross-platform (hence having unwarranted dependencies);
- requiring a graphical UI;
- requiring the user to press <kbd>Enter</kbd> before Python can see the input;
- requiring root privileges to install or run.

---

Is there a way for me, *as a non-root programmer*, to implement a Python 3 script, *runnable by non-root users, on the terminal CLI, in a Unix environment*, that will

1. print a prompt to stdout,
2. then read a ***single*** keypress from the user, and
3. then perform an action depending on the value of the key that the user pressed

?

I stress that I cannot use the (non-standard) `keyboard` module for this, because in order to install this module so that it's usable by non-root users one must have root priveleges, which I don't have.  Also, I do not want to saddle the script with a dependency solely to make it runnable on Windows, or any other non-Unix OS.  I.e. for my purposes here, minimizing dependencies is more important than cross-platform operability.

Answer (score 0):

This should work on unix/linux without issues (if not on python 3.12 you can adapt it with minimal changes):

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3.12

import sys
import tty
import termios
from contextlib import contextmanager

@contextmanager
def raw(f):
    fd = f.fileno()
    try:
        old = tty.setraw(fd, when=termios.TCSADRAIN)
        yield
    finally:
        termios.tcsetattr(fd, termios.TCSADRAIN, old)
    
def readch(f):
    with raw(f):
        return f.read(1)


print(f"prompt: ", end="", flush=True)
ch = readch(sys.stdin)
print(f"{ch} ({ord(ch)})")
```